# Конструкции как в ССП после двоеточия

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие

Предложение:

> У газетного листа впитывающая способность меньше, чем у обложки
>   глянцевого журнала: на него можно вылить меньше красок, и диапазон
>   цветов будет более узким.

Нужна ли запятая перед "и"? Теоретически это всё обобщено одним условием, которое до двоеточия, так что не факт. Дайте правило кто-нибудь, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С одной стороны, есть общая часть, чтобы не ставить запятую, но имеется следственная связь между частями (после двоеточия). Из-за этого логическое ударение падает на первую часть (после двоеточия) и оно не читается в одну фразу. Подобные взаимоотношения обозначаются паузой. Поэтому лучше поставить запятую.
*У газетного листа впитывающая способность меньше, чем у обложки глянцевого журнала: на него можно вылить меньше крАсок, и [вследствие/из-за этого] диапазон цветов будет более Узким.*

В общем, в таких случаях, если по задумке автора элементы читаются без паузы, запятая не ставится. Но нужно учитывать смысловую целесообразность.

Comment: А вы не думаете, что у каждого читателя свое чувство паузы. Если каждый будет выставлять знаки препинания, исходя из собственного чувства паузы, что тогда будет?

Comment: Одна часть ссылается на другую за счёт глагола. Как сказано в ответе, нужно учитывать смысловую целесообразность: читать всё подряд или выделить одно действие, а потом второе, исходящее от первого.

Comment: Я опять повторю: то, что для вас не чииается в одну фразу, для других может читаться в одну фразу. И вообще, у вас странный подход к синтаксису

Comment: Читайте в одну фразу всё и не ставьте вообще нигде запятых. Вы не слышите: взаимоотношения следствия обозначаются паузой. Поэтому **лучше** поставить запятую.

Comment: @Серж Оказалось, что это есть у Розенталя, и даже без ссылки на предыдущий элемент: https://i.imgur.com/OvgLopq.png

Comment: Тоже Розенталь (теперь уже больше): https://i.imgur.com/7OKftfB.png

Comment: Я знаю это правило. Но дело  не в паузе и не в задумке автора, как вы говорите. У Розенталя другое говорится: там сказано, что последняя часть не связана с первой.

Comment: Пауза - это последствие. Для того, чтобы показать следственные отношения, должно быть ударение на первый элемент и хоть какая-то пауза. Иначе их трудно уловить. (Не забываем, что при прямых следственных отношениях тире и увеличенная пауза.)

Comment: Так давайте выражается яснее: имеет следственные отношения. Интонационный принцип русской пунктуации занимает третье место, т. е. он не лидирующий.

Comment: Что касается этого примера, мне кажется, возможны оба варианта.

Comment: Часто бывает и то и то. Тогда нужно смотреть, что сильнее и важнее: отношение к первой или следствие из второй. Мне тоже казалось, что здесь возможны оба варианта, до того как прочитал об этом у Розенталя. Но теперь уверен, что если третья часть ссылается на вторую (глаголом или местоимением - "будет" никак к первой не относится), то корректно только с запятой. Хотя в разговорном варианте, грубо говоря, можно прочитать всё в одну фразу, не обращая внимания на ссылки. А где вы нашли иерархию принципов?

Comment: Прочитайте "Принципы русской пунктуации".

Answer (score 1):

*У газетного листа впитывающая способность меньше, чем у обложки глянцевого журнала: **на него можно вылить меньше красок и диапазон цветов будет более узким.***

При общей бессоюзной связи запятая перед И не ставится:

Розенталь, п. 2.3.http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

3) Общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями сложносочиненного предложения третья часть, предшествующая им и **связанная с ними бессоюзной связью.**

**Дополнение.**

Почему здесь вообще стоит **двоеточие,** если это причинно-следственные отношения? Отношения *причина — следствие* обозначаются по правилам тире. Скорее всего, двоеточие обозначает **пояснение**, а не причинную связь:

*У газетного листа впитывающая способность меньше, чем у обложки глянцевого журнала (**и это свойство можно использовать следующим образом**): на него можно вылить меньше красок и диапазон цветов будет более узким.*

Comment: Ну тут, условно говоря, сложносочиненное предложение после двоеточия. Если разорвать парцелляцией, будет так: 
"У газетного листа впитывающая способность меньше, чем у обложки глянцевого журнала. На него можно вылить меньше красок, и (тогда) диапазон цветов будет более узким". Не согласна про железное отсутствие запятой. Тут подразумевается следствие.

Comment: Просто оттенок следствия между 2 и 3 способствует наличию паузы и логическому ударению на 2. Это не значит, что 3 не будет относиться к 1. Бывает, что тире с запятой ставят, чтобы "оторваться" от двоеточия.

Comment: @oleedd,  а это ваша авторская теория о том, что предложения, связанные союзом И,  должны быть обязательно однородными или ссылку можете дать?  И почему там вообще стоит двоеточие, а не тире?  Можете объяснить?

Comment: Какая ещё теория? Если читаем без паузы в одну фразу, то и запятую не ставим. Посмотрите примеры Розенталя. Где там хоть один пример с настолько сильным следствием? Такое не читается в одну фразу. Хотя даже если логически подумать, то разнородное соединяется гораздо сложнее (про любую область деятельности). Согласен с вами, что тире лучше. А если и пояснение, то скорее первая часть поясняет остальное.

Comment: А теперь обратим внимание на само правило Розенталя: *Общей **может быть поясняемая** двумя частями сложносочиненного предложения третья часть, предшествующая им и связанная с ними бессоюзной связью.* Может быть, но не обязательно является. Вы уверены, что 3 поясняет 1? Глагол "*будет*" указывает на следствие из 2. Или после чего он будет?

Comment: Термин "чтение в одну фразу" не является общепринятым, откуда вы его взяли? Про сильное управление слышала, а про сильное следствие нет. Из Розенталя: Одно было ясно: ссора оказалась окончательной и назад он не вернётся;  Здесь есть следственные отношения? Почему нет запятой?

Comment: У меня к вам личная просьба: будьте более ответственными в своих высказываниях,  а то у меня появляется желание контролировать каждое ваше слово.

Comment: *Одно было ясно: назад он не вернётся и ссора оказалась окончательной.* Эти моменты были ясны. Местами можно поменять, но это хуже. Это читается в одну фразу. Элементы нераспространённые. Нет слов, указывающих на вытекание одного из другого. Были ясны два этих факта. Прямое отношение к первой части. Но в примере из  вопроса нет такого. 3 не поясняет 1. См. предыдущий комментарий с правилом. Сравнить: *Одно было ясно: ссора оказалась окончАтельной, и из-за этого назад он не вернётся.*  Или тут тоже не поставите запятую? (Есть ссылка на предыдущий элемент, как и в примере из вопроса.)

Comment: К вашему сведению: я утверждаю, что запятую **лучше** поставить; вы утверждали, что в любом случае запятая **не ставится** (ставить нельзя). Улавливаете разницу?

Comment: oleedd, пока, спокойной ночи. Давайте не превращать комментарии в чат. Вы дали свой ответ, я свой, пусть автор выбирает, что ему по вкусу. Или ничего не выбирает, на то его авторское право.

Comment: Оказалось, что это есть у Розенталя, и даже без ссылки на предыдущий элемент: https://i.imgur.com/OvgLopq.png

Comment: Тоже Розенталь (теперь уже больше): https://i.imgur.com/7OKftfB.png А если элемент как-либо ссылается на предыдущий (глаголом или местоимением), то это однозначно следствие.